# Finding roots with scipy.optimize.root

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the root y of a function called f using Python.

Here is my code:

```
 def f(y):
    w,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7 = y[:8] 
    t1 = w - 0.500371726*(p1**0.92894164) - (-0.998515304)*((1-p1)**1.1376649)
    t2 = w - 8.095873128*(p2**0.92894164) - (-0.998515304)*((1-p2)**1.1376649)
    t3 = w - 220.2054377*(p3**0.92894164) - (-0.998515304)*((1-p3)**1.1376649)
    t4 = w - 12.52760758*(p4**0.92894164) - (-0.998515304)*((1-p4)**1.1376649)
    t5 = w - 8.710859537*(p5**0.92894164) - (-0.998515304)*((1-p5)**1.1376649)
    t6 = w - 36.66350261*(p6**0.92894164) - (-0.998515304)*((1-p6)**1.1376649)
    t7 = w - 3.922692207*(p7**0.92894164) - (-0.998515304)*((1-p7)**1.1376649)       
    t8 = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 - 1
    return [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8]


x0 = np.array([-0.01,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
sol = scipy.optimize.root(f, x0, method='lm')
print sol 
print 'solution', sol.x
print 'success', sol.success
```

Python does not find the root whatever the method I try in scipy.optimize.root.

However there is one, I found it with the function fsolve in Matlab.

It is:

[-0.0622, 0.5855, 0.087, 0.0028, 0.0568, 0.0811, 0.0188, 0.1679].

When I specify x0 close to the root, the python algorithm converges. The problem is that I have no idea a priori on the root to specify x0. In reality I am solving many equations of this type.

I really want to use Python. Can anyone help me converge with python?

Comment: Hint1: provide a jacobian. Hint2: split the problem in 2. For a given `w`, you have 7 1d problems, (p1..p7), which are easier than one 8d problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scipy.optimize.root does not converge in Python while Matlab fsolve works, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630382/scipy-optimize-root-does-not-converge-in-python-while-matlab-fsolve-works-why)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Yes it also my question but it is different since the answer does not work in the present case.

Comment: There is no need to have a question for every set of parameters that don't converge in an optimization algorithm: that is expected. Update you previous question and un-accept the accepted answer if you find that it is insuficient to solve your actual problem (which seems to be "solving many equations of this type")

Comment: Believing that one can blindly use root finder or minimization routines without first really understanding your function and how a particular solver works is about as useful as praying to your favorite deity to print out the answer for you.  You have a python console and plotting capabilities - use them to explore how your function depends on $w$ and $p$. Play with different root finding methods and different starting values to understand where they work best in your ranges of interest. Use that knowledge to find the most robust method.  Each is excellent for some types of problems.

Comment: As a further comment: you appear to be trying to perform a constrained optimization (I gather that from your definition of t8 above). The appropriate scipy function to use there is scipy.optimize.minimize, using the constraints argument (limiting you to the COBYLA and SLSQP methods).

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you, do you mean It is better to minimize the squared output of f, using t8 as a constraint, then use directly a root finding algorithm?

Comment: That is correct - that will help the algorithm tremendously (well, usually - finders/solvers have a lot of black magic in them).

Comment: @JonCuster I tried minimizing the sum of squares using t8 as a constraint, and also root finding for 7 1d problems given w. My problem is that each method converges sometimes but not all the time (I have like 20 000 problems like the one described to solve). How can I do in this case? Should I combine several methods doing if this method does not work, try this method etc. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, after some fooling around, we focus on another aspect of good optimization/root finding algorithms.  In the comments above we went back and forth around which method in scipy.optimize.root() to use.  An equally important question for near-bulletproof 'automatic' root finding is zeroing in on good initial guesses.  Often times, good initial guesses are, in fact, not near the real answer at all.  Instead, they need to be arranged so that they will naturally lead the solver in the right direction.

In your particular case, your guesses were, in fact, sending the algorithm off in strange directions.

My toy reconstruction of your problem is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize
def f(y):
    w,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7 = y[:8]
    def t(p,w,a):       
        b = -0.998515304
        e1 = 0.92894164
        e2 = 1.1376649
        return(w-a*p**e1 - b*(1-p)**e2)
    t1 = t(p1,w,1.0)
    t2 = t(p2,w,4.0) 
    t3 = t(p3,w,16.0)
    t4 = t(p4,w,64.0)
    t5 = t(p5,w,256.0)
    t6 = t(p6,w,512.0)
    t7 = t(p7,w,1024.0)       
    t8 = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 - 1.0
    return(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8)
guess = 0.0001
x0 = np.array([-1000.0,guess,guess,guess,guess,guess,guess,guess])
sol = sp.optimize.root(f, x0, method='lm')
print('w=-1000: ', sol.x, sol.success,sol.nfev,np.sum(f(sol.x)))
```

Note that I did not use your specific prefactors (I wanted to broaden the range I explored), although I kept your particular exponents on the p terms.

The real secret is in the initial guess, which I made the same for all p terms. Having it a 0.1 or above bombed much of the time, since some terms want to go one way and some the other.  Reducing it to 0.01 worked well for this problem. (I will note that the w term is very robust - varying from -1000. to +1000. had no effect on the solution).  Reducing the initial guess even further has no effect on this particular problem, but it does no harm either.  I would keep it very small.

Yes, you know that at least some terms will be much larger.  But, you are putting the solver in a position where it can clearly and directly proceed towards the real solution.

Good luck.